# PHP session doesnt work sometimes

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Hello i saw some similar topics but answers doesnt satisfy me.
Im using sessions for logging into simple admin panel and im starting it with code:

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","3600");
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"]) && $_SESSION["logged"] == True)
...else show login form
```

Session worked on my VPS server, but then i moved site to my friends virtual host and session started "party". Sometimes it stays for some minutes and sometimes it dies after page refresh showing me login form.
Site is not in root directory it lies in subdirectory "/blog" just near wordpress files(friend wanted blog inside blog)

Current session setup shown by phpinfo is:

```
session.auto_start  Off Off  
session.bug_compat_42   On  On  
session.bug_compat_warn On  On  
session.cache_expire    180 180  
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache  
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value  
session.cookie_httponly Off Off  
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0  
session.cookie_path /   /  
session.cookie_secure   Off Off  
session.entropy_file    no value    no value  
session.entropy_length  0   0  
session.gc_divisor  100 100  
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440  
session.gc_probability  1   1  
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4  
session.hash_function   0   0  
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID  
session.referer_check   no value    no value  
session.save_handler    files   files  
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp  
session.serialize_handler   php php  
session.use_cookies On  On  
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off  
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Im not sitting in PHP normally, some say that i should change session directory, but i dont know how directories structure looks like in virtual hosting. But strange fact is that it currently works good on my Chrome/Win7 but totally dont work on Mac Safari. So i doubt that changing dir solve problem.
Also i have warning:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

Can it cause this problem?

Comment: That error means literally what it says: You cannot start the session because you've already sent data to the client. The proper way to fix this is to ensure you start the session BEFORE you send anything (even a newline character) to the client. The poor way to fix this is with buffered output.

Comment: you need to put `session_start();` on top of each page just after `<?php` and also there must not be any empty lines will be at the beginning or at at the end of the file. also `ob_start();ob_flush();ob_cleanup();` can used for this but not good at all

Comment: @kainaw Ok ill try. But html <head></head> can be after session_start?

Comment: @pszczelaszkov All html (including <head>) *must* come after session_start().